# Laravel Guzzle Could Not Resolve Host

Tags: php, laravel, curl, laravel-5, guzzle

I have a Laravel application which is hosted locally on a local IP.

It will always be hosted internally on the IP.

I'm trying to connect my application to Interlinks API, on sending a $client->post() I get the following error:

> ConnectException in CurlFactory.php line 186: cURL error 6: Could not
>   resolve host: headers (see
>   http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Below is the code in my controller.

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

        $client->setDefaultOption('headers', array('Accept' => 'application/json', 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'GEOSESSION' => 'MTAuMjYuMy43asdasdasdasdTky'));
        $body = json_encode($job);

        $res = $client->post('https://api.interlinkexpress.com/shipping/shipment',['body' => $body]);

        dd($res);
```

Does anyone have any ideas why I get the could not resolve host? I'm hoping it's nothing to do with being local.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the latest Guzzle (6.2 at the moment).

It seems that you are using older version, because `setDefaultOption` is not available in `6.x`.